# How can I make a BottomSheetDialogFragment non-modal?

Tags: android

In onCreateView() I've tried setting some properties, but the DialogFragment still goes away on tapping outside.

I would like the fragment to remain nearly all the time while the user interacts with other parts of the app.

This is in a class that extends BottomSheetDialogFragment:

```
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(
      LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    // makes background non-interactive
    getDialog().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);

    // prevents dimming of background
    getDialog().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);

    // no effect?
    getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    this.setCancelable(false);

    return view;
  }
```

Comment: Try `setCancelable(false)`.

Comment: Sorry, that was in my original code, but it had no effect. Any other suggestions or documentation that could explain this?

Comment: Why `this.setCancelable(false);` not `getDialog().setCancelable(false);` (or vice versa all calls on `this` object)?

Comment: Added notes - the above is in a class that extends BottomSheetDialogFragment, which is a DialogFragment. And the docs say to call it on the DialogFragment, not the inner Dialog. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html#setCancelable(boolean)

Comment: Actually, as I understand You should inherit from `DialogFragment` and override `public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) { ... ` method.

Comment: Why? More details / reasoning please.

Comment: It also doesn't work.

Comment: @dmonopoly Did you find a solution for your question?

Answer (score -2):

Code like:

```
    public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

        ...

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
            builder.setTitle(...)
                    .setMessage(...)
                    .setCancelable(false);

            ...

            Dialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.getWindow();
            return dialog;
        }

        ...

    }
```

works for me.